# Explain javascripts Date() functions

Tags: javascript, date

Why is it when I have

```
var dt = new Date(2015, 6, 1);
dt.toUTCString()
```

My output is `Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:00:00 GMT`

And

```
var dt = new Date(2015, 6, 2);
dt.toUTCString()
```

`Wed, 01 Jul 2015 23:00:00 GMT`

I'm clearly missing something here, I want to be able to loop through each days of the month and get a `Date()` for that day

I don't understand why if the day is 1, it says the date is the 30th

Comment: This is a good question, clear, useful and indeed interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript dates are always generated with local time zone. Using `toUTCString` converts the time in the Date object to UTC time, and apparently in your case that means -1 hours. If you want to initialize a Date object with UTC time, use:

```
var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1));
```

Comment: I think I'm just being stupid. I thought toUTCString() was the only function to view the readable date, just realized there's a toDateString() and that brings up the right date

Answer (score 0):

The toUTCString() method converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time.

The Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is the time set by the World Time Standard.

Note: UTC time is the same as GMT time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change dt.toUTCString() in another function.
There are a lot of hour on the planet,for example in America is the 5 o' Clock,in Japan is 10 o' Clock etc... the UTC is a time zone,try to change this.